# Easy Digital Download Sub category

Tags: plugins, categories

I'm curretnly developing my web store using the Easy digital downalod plugin.
Now my problem is that i'd like to show only the list of a subcategory and i can't seem to find a way to do so. I ran across a this snippet from sumobi:

```
<?php
/**
 * Output a list of EDD's terms (with links) from the 'download_category' taxonomy
*/
function sumobi_list_edd_terms() { 
    $taxonomy = 'download_category'; // EDD's taxonomy for categories
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy ); // get the terms from EDD's download_category      taxonomy
?>
<ul class="download-categories">
<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) : ?>
   <li>
       <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ) ); ?>" title="<? php echo $term->name; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Here's the link: http://sumobi.com/list-categories-with-links-in-easy-digital-downloads/

His code displays the category. Is there a way i can change it to make it display the subcategory of my category id=6?

Answer (score 1):

You can get only the category's children.

```
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, 'child_of=6' );
```

Answer (score 0):

that worked out but i had to find another way because if someone else has to use the theme, his/her id for that category might not correspond to mine. Here's the soultuion i found:
`code`

```
function my_list_edd_terms() { 
    $theCatId = get_term_by( 'slug', 'HorrorBooks', 'download_category' );
    $theCatId = $theCatId->term_id;
    $taxonomy = 'download_category';
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $theCatId, $taxonomy );
    echo'<ul class="download-categories">';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
            $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy );
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

The logic is the same but in this case,it uses the category slug to get the id and then fetch the sub categories.

Thanks all the same guys!.